# Node Docker Container - Caching Container Startup Logic

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Docker container pulls my Node App from Git and installs the required dependencies. However, this logic is re-run on subsequent calls to Docker Start after the initial run.  Is there a way I can setup my Entrypoint script to only pull the app from Git when Docker run is called? I am assuming I could always write a file into the container after the initial setup is completed and check for that file before pulling from Git?  Is there a better and more clean way to achieve this behavior?

Dockerfile:

```
# Generic Docker Image for Running Node app from Git Repository
FROM    node:0.10.33-slim
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Add script to pull Node app from Git and run the app
COPY docker-node-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["--help"]
```

Entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Run the command passed in if it isn't to start a node app
if [ "$1" != 'node-server' ]; then
   exec "$@"
fi
# Logic for pulling the node app and starting it
cd /usr/src
# try to remove the repo if it already exists
rm -rf node-app; true
echo "Pulling Node app's source from $2"
git clone $2 node-app
cd node-app
# Check if we should be running a specific commit from the git repo
if [ ! -z "$3" ]; then
  echo "Changing to commit $3"
  git checkout $3
fi
npm install
echo "Starting the app"
exec node .
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, each of your node projects would have its own Dockerfile, so rather than defering the `git clone` to `docker run` time, you would make containers that are fully set up and ready to run.

its likely that you could add a Dockerfile to each of your git repo's that contain a variation on

`FROM node:onbuild`, which would automatically default to running your node app too.

Comment: I understand building the source into a Docker container is the generally recommended way and understand how node:onbuild works.  I am experimenting with this approach since I don't want to embed my source into a container saved on docker hub. Also, I have a lot of node microservices and don't want to deal with a lot of different containers.  I would prefer to have just one I reuse.  The downside is that startup will take longer (to pull dependencies and app files) but based on my current experiments it is pretty quick.